# Howto drag & drop field images in editor

Tags: media, javascript

1. Is there any possibility/ module to multiupload e.g. 3 three images and drag/insert them into the text field (Body) to the position I want the Images?
2. After this it should open colorbox gallery when I click on this images in the content.

I painted my problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVWrK.jpg

regards,
l

Comment: there is always a "possibility" ... because you can code it if doesn't exist yet with the Drupal API. this is too vague of a series of workflow questions.

The Media module and Image Insert can do 1 basically. Colorbox and field formatter can do 2.

Comment: thaaaank u! insert is the module i searched for!!! update: the module is called "Insert"

Answer (score 2):

> [Insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) is a utility that makes inserting images and links to
>   files into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple
>   JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used
>   with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas
>   with a specific ImageCache preset.

[image]

2) Vimeo Screencast [Colorbox for Drupal 7, part 2: Inline images with the Insert module](http://vimeo.com/19386122)